# How to make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, named-pipes

I am building a windows service that communicates with other processes using [named pipe](https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper).
My unit test for the named pipe communication is throwing this error message 4 times:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded
>   AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not
>   stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are
>   stopped before completion.

Here's my unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ListenToNamedPipeTest()
    {
        var watcher = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        var svc = new WindowService();
        svc.ClientMessageHandler += (connection, message) => watcher.Reset();
        svc.ListenToNamedPipe();
        sendMessageToNamedPipe("bla");
        var wait = watcher.WaitOne(1000);

        svc.Dispose();

        Assert.IsTrue(wait, "No messages received after 1 seconds");
    }

    private void sendMessageToNamedPipe(string text)
    {
        var client = new NamedPipeClient<Message, Message>(DeviceCertificateService.PIPE_NAME);
        client.ServerMessage += (conn, message) => Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Text);

        // Start up the client asynchronously and connect to the specified server pipe.
        // This method will return immediately while the client runs in a separate background thread.
        client.Start();

        client.PushMessage(new Message { Text = text });

        client.Stop();
    }
```

How do I make all threads stop before my unit test stops?

Thanks

---

UPDATE:

The named pipe client does not have a `close()` function:

```
// Type: NamedPipeWrapper.NamedPipeClient`2
// Assembly: NamedPipeWrapper, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: D2B99F4D-8C17-4DB6-8A02-29DCF82A4118
// Assembly location: C:\Users\Thang.Duong\Source\Workspaces\Post Tracking System\Applications\Dev\OHD\packages\NamedPipeWrapper.1.5.0\lib\net40\NamedPipeWrapper.dll

using System;

namespace NamedPipeWrapper
{
  public class NamedPipeClient<TRead, TWrite> where TRead : class where TWrite : class
  {
    public NamedPipeClient(string pipeName);
    public void Start();
    public void PushMessage(TWrite message);
    public void Stop();
    public void WaitForConnection();
    public void WaitForConnection(int millisecondsTimeout);
    public void WaitForConnection(TimeSpan timeout);
    public void WaitForDisconnection();
    public void WaitForDisconnection(int millisecondsTimeout);
    public void WaitForDisconnection(TimeSpan timeout);
    public bool AutoReconnect { get; set; }
    public event ConnectionMessageEventHandler<TRead, TWrite> ServerMessage;
    public event ConnectionEventHandler<TRead, TWrite> Disconnected;
    public event PipeExceptionEventHandler Error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need .close and .dispose on both the server and the client?

Comment: Neither the client or server has a `Close()` function. Each has a `Stop()` function though.

Comment: ManualResetEvent has a close - did you try that? It looks like that's the only thread you're spawning.

Comment: ManualResetEvent does not have a `Close()` function either.

Comment: What is the namespace then? I was assuming: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx which inherits close from WaitHandle.

Comment: Ah, I found the `ManualResetEvent.Close()` function. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118590/discussion-between-gamerj5-and-believe2014).

Comment: look at the design pattern ScopeLock. In C# you can implement it with the key word "Using". In this case you will be sure that whatever why you test finish your object would be correctly disposed.

Answer (score 3):

My `WindowsService` inherits the `ServiceBase` class which has the `Dispose()` function to close all threads. That's why I get all racing errors.

I had to avoid calling `Dispose()` function and replace it with `client.Close()` and `svc.Close()` function. The `svc.Close()` function is my custom implementation to stop and close the named pipe server.